# Creating CoordinateMatrix from DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, distributed-computing

I have a dataframe containing all numerical values with an undefined number of columns and rows. The dataframe is too large to work with locally but the end goal is to compute X^TX where X is the dataframe/matrix. I am attempting to convert the dataframe into a CoordinateMatrix and then into a block matrix so that it can be multiplied with itself while distributed. In order to do this, I need to pass the constructor a MatrixEntry which requires the row and column numbers. However, I am unsure how to get these from the dataframe while mapping it. If anyone knows how to do this or a better way to implement this, it would be much appreciated.